# Find the area of the triangle $ABC$ right angled at $C$ for the given data.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, solution-verification

The triangle $ABC$, right angled at $C$, has median $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$. $AD$ lies along the line $y = x + 3$, $BE$ lies
along the line $y = 2x + 4$. If the length of the hypotenuse is $60$, find the area of the triangle $ABC$.

[image]
Let $AC=b$, $BC=a$

$$a^2+b^2=60^2$$

$$\triangle_{ABC}=\dfrac{1}{2}ab\tag{1}$$

Let's take a look at $\angle AGB$

Case $1$: $\angle AGB=\theta$ is acute

$$\tan\theta=\left|\dfrac{1-2}{1+2}\right|$$
$$\tan\theta=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Applying cosine rule in $\triangle_{AGB}$

$$\cos\theta=\dfrac{AG^2+GB^2-AB^2}{2AG\cdot GB}\tag{2}$$

As $G$ is centroid, so $AG=\dfrac{2}{3}AD$, $GB=\dfrac{2}{3}BE$

$$AD=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}$$
$$AD=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{4c^2-3a^2}\tag{3}$$

$$BE=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{4c^2-3b^2}\tag{4}$$

$$\cos\theta=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{9}\left(4c^2-3b^2+4c^2-3a^2\right)-c^2}{\dfrac{2}{9}\sqrt{4c^2-3a^2}\sqrt{4c^2-3b^2}}$$

$$\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{10}}=\dfrac{-4c^2}{\sqrt{4c^2-3a^2}\sqrt{4c^2-3b^2}}$$

This is not possible as $L.H.S$ is positive and $R.H.S$ is negative, so $\theta$ must have been obtuse. So $\cos\theta=\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}$

Hence above expression can be written as

$$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}=\dfrac{2c^2}{\sqrt{4c^2-3a^2}\sqrt{4c^2-3b^2}}$$

Squaring both sides

$$9(4c^2-3a^2)(4c^2-3b^2)=40c^4$$
$$9(16c^4-12b^2c^2-12a^2c^2+9a^2b^2)=40c^4$$
$$144c^4-108c^4+9a^2b^2=40c^4$$
$$9a^2b^2=4c^4$$
$$ab=\pm\dfrac{2}{3}c^2$$

As $a$ and $b$ are sides, so $ab$ will be positive, hence $ab=2400$

Hence, area of triangle is $\dfrac{1}{2}ab=1200$, but actual answer is $400$

Answer (score 1):

You went wrong near the end. You got
$$9(16c^4-12b^2c^2-12a^2c^2+9a^2b^2)=40c^2$$ We have $a^2+b^2=c^2$ so 
$$9(16c^4-12c^4+9a^2b^2)=40c^4$$ and hence
$$81a^2b^2=(40-36)c^4$$
So $ab=\frac{2}{9}c^2=$ and the area is $60^2/9=400$.